# SQL Select SUM if ID is the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this is probably a simple question since I'm still learning, but I am trying to find a SQL Select statement that will calculate the SUM of each row's pieces and weight IF their secondary IDs are the same.  So the select is collapsing and getting the SUM of rows with the same secondary ID, while also returning the unique rows as well.

```
ID_a  ID_b  pieces  weight
--------------------------
1     1     10      20
2     1     20      30
3     2     40      40
```

Will result in

```
ID_b: 1  pieces: 30  weight: 50
ID_b: 2  pieces: 40  weight: 40
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by the `id_b` and then you can use aggregate functions to sum up the values for each group

```
select id_b, sum(pieces), sum(weight)
from your_table
group by id_b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id_b,sum(pieces),sum(weight)
from table 
group by id_b
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT TID_b
      ,SUM(pieces) AS [totalPieces]
      ,SUM(weight) AS [totalWeight]
FROM yourTable T
GROUP BY T.ID_b
```

Hope this will help you.